# Generate a fixed length number hash from a number

Tags: algorithms, security, hashing

Let say I've a fixed length number, e.g. 6 digit: 837493, I want to apply some process (with a salt), and generate a new number of another 6 digits,

e.g.

```
number = 837493
another = hash(number + salt) // another is also a 6 digit number, e.g. 948375
```

Are there such algorithm exists?

Comment: Yep, any hash algorithm based on [sponge construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sponge_function)

Comment: What are you going to use this for? Is this for some kind of security application? If yes, then I highly discourage you making up your own hashing algorithm.

Comment: do leading zeros count?

Comment: What security goals do you have? Hashing to 6 decimal digits is easy, but I have severe doubts that what you're trying to do is secure. Such a short hash can be neither collision nor pre-image resistant.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but when you say *new number* - you just mean any 6 digit number that isn't the input one - correct?